# Create lines to connect vertices in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, intersection

I have a file that marks street edges and want to connect "crossing" points automatically. Image 1 shows the street edge, Image 2 shows the desired result. Is there a plugin or method I can use to accomplish this without having to scroll through and create a new line at each intersection?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The data you're looking for might already exist, possibly through open street map. Or you could download street lines, and add a buffer. It depends on what you need the data for and how precise you need it to be.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is for a new development, so would not exist on Open Street Maps. I created this from a buffer of the line file, so went from line, buffered to the width of the street, and converted polygon to line at this point.

Comment: As long as the streets are separate lines, this is a simple fix. Redo the buffer step and choose the option to not dissolve the resulting buffers.